# Exponential random variable given parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume X that is an exponential random variable with parameter 9. Evaluate ln $\frac{1}{P(X^2 + 10 X \geq 24)}$

How do I solve this? Do I integrate the ln?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**.

- For any $p > 0$, $\ln(1/p)=\ln1-\ln p=-\ln p$.
- Since $x^{2}+10x-24=(x-2)(x+12)$, letting $F$ denote the CDF of the random variable $X$,
  \begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(X^{2}+10X\ge24)&=\mathbb{P}(X^{2}+10X-24\geq0)\\
  & = 1-\mathbb{P}(X^{2}+10X-24<0)\\
  & =1-\mathbb{P}(-12<X<2) \\
  & =1 - F(2) + F(-12)
  \end{align*}

Comment: Could you tell me if this is right? Since P (X $\leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x} $ Do i just put in 2 and -12 in place of the x? Thank you.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So when i did  -ln (1 + (1 - e^(-18) + (1 - e^(108)) I get an error, why is this not correct? Thank you

Comment: $F(-12)=0$, not $1-e^{-9\cdot12}$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).